# Can Handler return a Future object?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Can I get a future object from a handler?

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
Future<String> future = handler.post(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throw Exception {
        // run in the main thread
        return askForPassword();
    }
}); // can I do something like this?
String password = future.get(); // wait until finish
// do network things...
```

I have a network thread and I need to ask the user for password, since I need to show an input dialog I have to do this on Main thread, but handler can not return values.
I can do the same thing by

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
String password = null;
handler.post(() -> {
    // run in the main thread
    password = askForPassword();
});
while (password == null) { /*wait until finish*/ }
// do network things...
```

But this looks stupid and inconvenient

Comment: No.  Handler only returns a boolean when you post (returning success of adding you to the queue or not).  It does not return a future under any circumstance.  Your 2nd code won't work either though-  you can only access final variables in inner classes.  You can't return a value through that method.  Usually you would get the password before you make the thread, and pass it in to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

`Handler` is fundamentally asynchronous and thus whatever you put there is not guaranteed to run immediately (moreover, you can `postDelayed` or `postAtTime`). Then it is clear, that you can not return any value from the `Handler` directly to the code that posted it. So you have to work this around.

Another obstacle is that in Java your closure can capture only `final` variables and you have to work this around as well.

**New API (`CompletableFuture`)**

Unfortunately original `Future` Java API is not suitable for composition. If you target new devices only and thus can use newer [`CompletableFuture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), you may do something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> askForPasswordNewApi() {
     // your UI code that creates Future
}

void doNetworkThingNewApi() {
    // some network stuff

    final CompletableFuture<String> passwordFutureWrapper = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run in the main thread
            CompletableFuture<String> future = askForPasswordNewApi();
            // bind the real future to the outer one
            future.handle((r, ex) -> {
                if (ex != null)
                    passwordFutureWrapper.completeExceptionally(ex);
                else
                    passwordFutureWrapper.complete(r);
                return 0;
            });
        }
    });

    // wait until finish
    // don't forget to handle InterruptedException here
    String password = passwordFutureWrapper.get(); 

    // do more network things...
}
```

The idea is rather simple: create outer `final` variable `passwordFutureWrapper` that can be captured by the `Handler` and bind this wrapper to the real `future`

***Side note***: if your `askForPassword` already returns `Future` but you can't use the new API, you probably have re-implemented something similar to `CompletableFuture` anyway, so you just need to modify this code a bit to allow binding of one future to another.

**Old API**

If you can't use `CompletableFuture` in your code yet, but still somehow has a method with a `Future`-based signature:

```
Future<String> askForPasswordOldApi()
```

you may do it more explicitly:

```
void doNetworkThingOldApi() {
    // some network stuff

    final CountDownLatch syncLock = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Future<String>[] futureWrapper = new Future<String>[1];

    Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run in the main thread
            final CompletableFuture<String> future = askForPasswordOldApi();
            futureWrapper[0] = future;
            syncLock.countDown();
        }
    });


    String password;
    try {
        // 1 minute should be quite enough for synchronization between threads
        if (!syncLock.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            // log error, show some user feedback and then stop further processing
            return;
        }
        password = futureWrapper[0].get(); // wait until finish
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // log error, show some user feedback and then stop further processing
        return;
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        // log error, show some user feedback and then stop further processing
        return;
    }

    // do more network things...
}
```

The idea here is following:

1. Use single-element array as a simple container to work around `final`-closure limitations
2. Use `CountDownLatch` to ensure synchronization between the network and the UI threads i.e. that `futureWrapper[0]` is not null by the time we start waiting on the result with `get`.

**Update** (design for library API)

If you are designing API and want to have a single entry for login with different additional scenarios handled by a callback, I'd do using custom implementation of something similar to `CompletableFuture`:

```
public interface ResultHandler<T> {
    void resolve(T result);

    void cancel();
}


class ResultHandlerImpl<T> implements ResultHandler<T> {

    enum State {
        Empty,
        Resolved,
        Cancelled
    }


    private final Object _lock = new Object();
    private State _state = State.Empty;
    private T _result;


    @Override
    public void resolve(T result) {
        synchronized (_lock) {
            if (_state != State.Empty) // don't override current state
                return;

            _result = result;
            _state = State.Resolved;
            _lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        synchronized (_lock) {
            if (_state != State.Empty) // don't override current state
                return;

            _state = State.Cancelled;
            _lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }


    public boolean isCancelled() {
        synchronized (_lock) {
            return _state == State.Cancelled;
        }
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        synchronized (_lock) {
            return _state == State.Resolved;
        }
    }

    public T get() throws InterruptedException, CancellationException {
        while (_state == State.Empty) {
            synchronized (_lock) {
                _lock.wait();
            }
        }
        if (_state == State.Resolved)
            return _result;
        else
            throw new CancellationException();
    }
}
```

I would probably make interface `public` but implementation `ResultHandlerImpl` package-private so it would be harder for the users to mess up with implementation details. Then in callback methods I'd pass my callback `ResultHandler` as a parameter (actually it obviously would be a `ResultHandlerImpl`):

```
public interface LoginCallback {
    void askForPassword(ResultHandler<String> resultHandler);
}
```

And my `login` method would look something like this (assuming you have private methods `tryRestoreSession` that doesn't need password and `loginWithPassword` that requires):

```
public boolean login(final LoginCallback loginCallback) {
    if (tryRestoreSession()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        final ResultHandlerImpl<String> passwordHandler = new ResultHandlerImpl<>();

        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run in the main thread
                loginCallback.askForPassword(passwordHandler);
            }
        });
        String password;
        try {
            password = passwordHandler.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return loginWithPassword(password);
    }
}
```

What I think is important here:

1. I think that passing a callback to `LoginCallback` makes it easier to write an asynchronous UI-based implementation using standard Java.
2. `ResultHandlerImpl` has `cancel` method. So if the user, for example, forgot the password there is a way to cancel whole login process and not get stuck with a background thread waiting for a password forever
3. `ResultHandlerImpl` uses explicit synchronization and `wait`/`notifyAll` to establish [`happens-before`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) relationship between actions on different threads to avoid.
4. `ResultHandlerImpl` uses `wait`/`notifyAll` so the background thread doesn't consume CPU (and battery) while waiting for the UI.

Comment: I can't use CompletableFuture because of the api. I guess I can use a StringWrapper in my 2nd code. But is there any better ways to get user input(in main thread) from another thread? I think this is a common problem and there should be some better solutions.

Comment: @Zhh, as Gabe Sechan also suggested, I don't think that getting input from UI in the middle of a non-UI thread is a common problem. Actually I think that making it reliable on the UI-side, handling various bad scenarios (what if device is rotated? what if UI is already in some modal state? what if this happened exactly at the moment of navigation between two Activities? what if two threads want this at the same time?) is a quite complicated problem (much more complicated than this question). Usually you get something from UI first and pass **_all_** required data to the background thread.

Comment: In my case I have a login method which takes a callback interface as parameter. If password is required then I call the callback's askForPassword() method. Of course I can split the method into 3 methods: 1)check if password is required in the network thread 2)if password is required then call askForPassword() in the main thread 3)continue to login in the network thread. Actually I have more than one callback method besides askForPassword(). If I split the method it would be a big trouble to do such a login action.

Comment: @zzh, is this design of the `login` method signature yours design or was it enforced by something (i.e. can you change it)? Also, what is the real signature of the `askForPassword` method, especially returned type? Is it really `Future<String>`? What is the real type of the returned object? How it deals with the fact that this method involves interaction with a user?

Comment: I'm writing a library which contains a login method, and it accepts a callback interface which has method like ```askForPassword()```, it is the user who call login method to decide how to generate a password(such as showing a dialog).

Comment: "wait and notify" is a good idea, I didn't think that before. But I have a little question about synchronization. Why ```isCanceled```, ```isDone``` and ```_lock.wait()``` need to be synchronized?

Comment: I think ```set(result)``` and ```set(null)``` are similar to ```resolve(result)``` and ```cancel()```. I treat ```null``` as "cancel" so I don't need ```CancellationException``` and ```_state``` can then have two values ```Empty``` and ```Resolved``` so a boolean variable like ```ready``` is enough. I updated my answer to "wait and notify" style.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED using "wait and notify" instead of looping

UPDATED 2 synchronized methods

Finally I end up with object wrapper(thansk to @SergGr ) and handler

```
class ObjectWrapper<T> {
    T object;
    boolean ready;

    synchronized void set(T object) {
        this.object = object;
        this.ready = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    T get() {
        while (!ready) { 
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return null;
                }        
            }  
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

In my network thread

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
ObjectWarpper<String> wrapper = new ObjectWarpper<>();
handler.post(() -> wrapper.set(askForPassword()));
String password = wrapper.get();
```

Comment: A nice way to thank Serggr would be to upvote and/or to accept his answer. :-)

Comment: @Zhh, what you provided here is a very bad code that contains 2 classical multi-threading mistakes (busy waiting and lack of proper synchronization) and there is also what I would call a design mistake (no way to cancel). In short if you are unlucky enough on some (future) devices you might hang forever just burning electricity on the CPU.

Comment: @SergGr I don't think synchronization is a problem, once set is called, get will return immediately as long as set and get are not in the same thread and get is not called before set. object and ready may be modified by more than one thread, if that happens, object may be uncertain and get will return immediately. Busy waiting is a problem

Comment: @zhh, But `get` will be called before `set`. Or why else do you need the `while` inside? I think you should learn more about [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) and what optimizations JVM allows. Without synchronization JIT is allowed to generate code that will not re-read `ready` from the memory for every `while` iteration (and would always use the value cached in register). Or the CPU might optimize memory access (cache) for different cores that run the `get` and `set` threads with the same results. See also Example 17.4-1 in the link.

Comment: @SergGr You are right. I have tested it on android then I found that synchronization is required when call wait() and notifyAll(). I have updated my answer. I think this will be no problem.

Comment: @zhh IMO solving a concurrency problem with 'volitile' is like taking the guard rails off a mountain road because you are hitting them; I have a similar but less severe opinion of synchronized blocks. Don't get frustrated though; concurrency is one of the hardest problems to code for; many people work hard to solve it coherently. Literature suggestion: check out Java: Concurrency in Practice, Ch 13&14 of Mark Miller's thesis, and maybe the ReactiveX manifesto if you think you'll be dealing with concurrency often.